# Discord bot using Python gives AttributeError

Tags: python, discord.py, pycord

I want to make a quick ticket help bot for my friend, but the code that I wrote had this error(that is a small summary):

```
AttributeError: 'Interaction' object has no attribute 'selected_options'
```

Here’s the code

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import bottoken #A custom file for my bot token
from keep_alive import keep_alive #An other custom file that have a code makes the code still working for long time

BotIntents = discord.Intents.all() #That was for testing only

Bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="#", intents=BotIntents)

needs = [...]

respons = [...]

class support_select(discord.ui.View):
    @discord.ui.select(
        placeholder="إختيار الدعم التلقائي",
        min_values=1,
        max_values=1,
        options=[
            discord.SelectOption(label=neededs[0], description=""),
            discord.SelectOption(label=neededs[1], description=""),
            discord.SelectOption(label=neededs[2], description=""),
            discord.SelectOption(label=neededs[3], description="")
        ]
    )
    async def select_callback(self, select,interaction):
        selected_options = select.selected_options
        for option in selected_options:
            if option == neededs[0]:
                await interaction.response.send_message(
                f"# {option}\n\n{respon[0]}\n\nSport Speed Support",
                ephemeral=True
            )
            elif option == neededs[1]:
                await interaction.response.send_message(
                f"# {option}\n\n{respon[1]}\n\nSport Speed Support",
                ephemeral=True
            )
            elif option == neededs[2]:
                await interaction.response.send_message(
                f"# {option}\n\n{respon[2]}\n\nSport Speed Support",
                ephemeral=True
            )
            elif option == neededs[3]:
                await interaction.response.send_message(
                f"# خريطة السيرفر\n\n{respon[3]}\n\nSport Speed Support",
                ephemeral=True
            )
        
@Bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("The bot {0.user}({0.user.id}) is online and ready to use...".format(Bot))

@Bot.command(name='ts')
async def ts(ctx):
    if ctx.author == Bot.user:
        return
    await ctx.send(view=support_select())

keep_alive() #That is from my own keep alive file

Bot.run(bottoken.ToKeN)
```

I tried to change a lot of things in the function `select_callback()` but sometimes give me another error and other times gives me the same error.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete error report starting with the word **traceback**. You can surround the report with 3` before and 3` after to properly format the output.  In addition, under what conditions to you get the error?

Comment: The docs for [@discord.ui.select](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html#id2) clearly state that the three parameters of the callback should be `self, interaction, select`. So the attribute-error is exactly as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found an answer for that, at function `send_callback` i have to replace the `select.selected_option` with `select.values[0]` and remove the for loop, please anyone had this error do that.